# os.popen('110', '110') throws ValueError: invalid mode '110'

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python script to convert a live webcam feed to a ascii type image. so far here is the code:

```
import cv2
import os

########################################################################
# SETTINGS #
SHOW_REAL_VIDEO = False   # Set this to True to get real camera video from cv2

########################################################################


def convert_row_to_ascii(row):
    # 17-long
    ORDER = (' ', '.', "'", ',', ':', ';', 'c', 'l',
             'x', 'o', 'k', 'X', 'd', 'O', '0', 'K', 'N')
    return tuple(ORDER[int(x / (255 / 16))] for x in row)[::-1]


def convert_to_ascii(input_grays):
    return tuple(convert_row_to_ascii(row) for row in input_grays)


def print_array(input_ascii_array):
    os.system("clear")
    print('\n'.join((''.join(row) for row in input_ascii_array)), end='')


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF != ord('q')):
    # Get screensize for reduction
    screen_height, screen_width = os.popen('110', '110r').read().split()

    # Get image data
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert data to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Reduce grayscale array to proper resolution
    reduced = cv2.resize(gray, (int(screen_width), int(screen_height)))

    # Plug in reduced resolution numpy array for ascii converter func
    converted = convert_to_ascii(reduced)
    print_array(converted)

    # Display the resulting frame
    if SHOW_REAL_VIDEO:
        cv2.imshow('frame', reduced)

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it keeps giving me an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/asciicamera/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    screen_height, screen_width = os.popen('110', '110').read().split()
  File "C:\python\lib\os.py", line 978, in popen
    raise ValueError("invalid mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: invalid mode '110'
[ WARN:0@2.007] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

can anyone tell me why this is happening? I tried to change the values of the frame a couple times but it still gave this error. Did I miss a line of code or something?

Comment: You're opening a file in the wrong mode? Maybe its an open flag

Comment: what is `os.popen('110', '110')` supposed to accomplish? that is the issue, not anything to do with OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows, you can get the screen resolution this way:

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

print("Width =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Height =", GetSystemMetrics(1))
```